# Python - Cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, unpack

I'm trying to get an Image's pixel RGB with the `PIL` `Image` Library.

With this code, I ran into the error:

```
for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):

        r,g,b=(image.getpixel((i,j))) #THIS LINE IS REFERENCED IN ERROR MESSAGE
        print("leds[",j,"] = CRGB(",r, "," ,g, ",", b, ");") #print pixel colorchange to console

del image
```

Why do I get this error?
To me, this seems really strange. I input 2 images and it works just fine. However when I have white pixels at a certain position in the image, I get the error:

```
line 18, in <module> 
r,g,b=(image.getpixel((i,j))) #Get pixel at coordinate
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

The Images that worked:
[ColorCycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUXdd.png),
[HelloWorld](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncoqq.png)

Image that didnt work:
[HelloWorld2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEoa0.png)
This Image has a few white pixels on the right.

Full code [here](https://pastebin.com/zvGWc2Kh).

Comment: are the images all of the same dimension?

Comment: Yes they are all 64x8 (W,H) pixels

Comment: It looks like the image might not be a multi-layer image, so the pixel value is an integer, not a tuple, as mentioned in [the documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getpixel). (Also, instead of using `print`'s string concatenation, you might want to consider using a [formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), like `f"leds[{j}] = CRGB({r}, {g}, {b})"`.)

Comment: @jirassimok what is a multi-layer image and why would that be the issue? It works with other images but not that single one with white pixels on the side.

Comment: The documentation indicates that `getpixel` returns a tuple only for images with multiple channels (aka [bands](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#bands) in the documentation) (I'm not sure why the documentation uses "multi-layer" in that case, unless it also refers to something else for some image formats.). Taking a look at the image you supplied, this does appear to be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the image you are looking at is not an RGB image. If you look at `image.getbands()` or `image.mode`, you will see that the image is in mode `P`, [the palette mode](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#palette).

In this mode, instead of storing values color values directly for each pixel, each pixel stores one number, which is an index into the image's palette, which is accessible via [`getpalette`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getpalette). The palette itself could be in a variety of "modes," but for this particular image, it is an RGB palette of the form `[r0, g0, b0, r1, g1, b1, ...]`.

So one way to get the actual pixel values of the image would be to check the mode and manually get the `r`, `g`, `b`, values out.

```
palette = image.getpalette()
for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
        index = image.getpixel((i, j))  # index in the palette
        base = 3 * index  # because each palette color has 3 components
        r, g, b = palette[base:base+3]
```

However, there is a shortcut in this case; you can convert between modes using the aptly-named [`convert` function](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert).

```
rgb_image = image.convert('RGB')
```

Note, however, that using `convert` blindly may have unexpected consequences (possibly without causing any Python errors) if you run into images that use other modes.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Only question left is how adding a few more pixels to an image of mode RGB converts it to mode P? Does this have anything to do with how paint.net exports .png images or is it maybe the count of white pixels which causes the change in mode?

Comment: It has to do with how the images were created, not the images' contents: if you save the result of `image.convert('RGB')`, it will look exactly the same, but will open in RGB mode if you open it again with PIL.