# Unused variables and TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Tags: python, typeerror, unused-variables

Hello I'm a newbie at python. In my function, I keep getting warnings of unused variables r,g,b,a. Can someone explain it for me?

```
def encode_image(self,img, msg):
        length = len(msg)
        if length > 255:
            print("text too long! (don't exeed 255 characters)")
            return False
        encoded = img.copy()
        width, height = img.size
        index = 0
        for row in range(height):
            for col in range(width):
                if img.mode != 'RGB':
                    r, g, b ,a = img.getpixel((col, row))
                elif img.mode == 'RGB':
                    r, g, b = img.getpixel((col, row))
                # first value is length of msg
                if row == 0 and col == 0 and index < length:
                    asc = length
                elif index <= length:
                    c = msg[index -1]
                    asc = ord(c)
                else:
                    asc = b
                encoded.putpixel((col, row), (r, g , asc))
                index += 1
        return encoded
```

```
Unused variable 'a' pylint(unused-variable)
Unused variable 'r' pylint(unused-variable)
Unused variable 'g' pylint(unused-variable)
Unused variable 'b' pylint(unused-variable)
```

```
   r, g, b ,a = img.getpixel((col, row))
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59723475/python-cannot-unpack-non-iterable-int-object

Comment: tksm! what about the unused variables? Should I care about it?

Comment: That's just a lint warning as others have said. You don't use the variables after defining them, so you don't need to define them at all

Answer (score 1):

Your check `if img.mode !='RGB'` is not sufficient. Seems like your image is greyscale, hence `getpixel()` will only return one integer value, hence it cannot split an integer into 4 variables. (i.e. can't unpack to 4 variables)

Use `img.getbands()` to find how many bands are there and then unpack accordingly.

Comment: Hello it seems like it work with RGB image and not with P-mode, meaning white-ish picture results in this error. But I still don't understand the unused variables warnings, should I do anything about it?

Comment: Pylint is a code checker, it tells you the unused variables in your code, hence saving system resources. You can ignore this for now. Its useful for large projects where every byte counts.